# While loop doesn't work in Android but works in a normal Java class?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, matcher

Hi I am having a problem with my while loop in the getAmatch() function

It doesn't enter the while loop in android but enters in a normal Java class.

Comment: Can anyone give me an answer to this problem its been killing me for a while arg!

Comment: What are the (real) values of `st` and `pattern`?

Comment: pattern is A........k   and I am taking in a dictionary.txt file splitting it into sets of word length then I am searching the set for the pattern.  `String st = getSingleString(wordMap.get(edit.length()));`

Comment: I don't know why you deleted the code from the question.  Presumably you don't want an answer anymore.  Certainly it is unanswerable in its current state.

Comment: There was a few mistakes, didn't want anyone making the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I can say off the top of my head without a bit more information is watch your case sensitivity on both input and patterns, and your while loop is a good piece of evidence; your `matcher.find()` is simply not finding a match. As it states in the [`documentation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29):

**Parameters:**

> *start:*  The index in the input at which
>   the find operation is to begin. If
>   this is less than the start of the
>   region, it is automatically adjusted
>   to that value. If it is beyond the end
>   of the region, the method will fail.

**Returns:**

```
true if (and only if)** a match has been found.
```

Comment: The thing is it works no problem in a normal Java class this is whats annoying me, would it be anything to do with Android?